# Is there a way to download an excel file (with multiple sheets) from google drive in Julia?

Tags: julia, xlsx

I´ve tried using google_download(“URL”, “local_path”) from “GoogleDrive” library, but it seems to only get the first sheet in csv format.

Have any clue?

Comment: You need to provide the source code that you were trying to use.

Comment: I wrote a long answer, but you probably just want to specify the format as xlsx and then export each sheet individually from the local xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the guts of `GoogleDrive.jl` is just doing some url manipulation.

https://github.com/tejasvaidhyadev/GoogleDrive.jl/blob/master/src/GoogleDrive.jl#L26

```
isg_sheet(url) = occursin("docs.google.com/spreadsheets", url)
isg_drive(url) = occursin("drive.google.com", url)

function sheet_handler(url; format=:csv)
    link, expo = splitdir(url)
    if startswith(expo, "edit") || expo == ""
        url = link * "/export?format=$format"
    elseif startswith(expo, "export")
        url = replace(url, r"format=([a-zA-Z]*)(.*)"=>SubstitutionString("format=$format\\2"))
    end
    url
end

function google_download(url, localdir)
    long_url = unshortlink(url)
    if isg_sheet(long_url)

        long_url = sheet_handler(long_url)
    end

    if isg_drive(long_url)
        drive_download(long_url, localdir)
    else
        DataDeps.fetch_http(long_url, localdir)
    end
end
```

## Google Sheets API

If you want to do much more than that you need to actually use the Google Sheet's API.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}
```

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet

With the GET on a spreadsheet id (found in the URL for the spreadsheet) the response contains the ids for all the sheets in the spreadsheet.

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": string,
  "properties": {
    object (SpreadsheetProperties)
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      object (Sheet)
    }
  ],
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      object (NamedRange)
    }
  ],
  "spreadsheetUrl": string,
  "developerMetadata": [
    {
      object (DeveloperMetadata)
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can pull out those sheet id's and do something with them, such as do an export request on each with a format of csv.

## Manually scape the `gid` for each sheet

If you don't want to use the API, and just copy those ids out of the browser URL as you click on each, you may be able to turn them into download links.

To get them to go thru the export link properly you need to pass the gid into the export url like so:

(This is a slightly modified version of `GoogleDrive.sheet_handler` that takes in the sheet gid)

```
function sheet_handler(url; format=:csv, sheet_gid=0)
    link, expo = splitdir(url)
    if startswith(expo, "edit") || expo == ""
        url = link * "/export?format=$format&gid=$sheet_gid"
    elseif startswith(expo, "export")
        url = replace(url, r"format=([a-zA-Z]*)(.*)"=>SubstitutionString("format=$format&gid=$sheet_gid\\2"))
    end
    url
end
```

So for my example test sheet I had three sheets with the following gids

- Sheet1, gid=0
- Sheet2, gid=972467363
- Sheet3, gid=1251741166

So to grab the third one, I did this:

```
DataDeps.fetch_http(sheet_handler(url; format=:csv, sheet_gid=1251741166), ".")
```

Here is the example run:

```
julia> using GoogleDrive

julia> using GoogleDrive.DataDeps

julia> url = read("link.txt", String)
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13-LtgMi8evaxGxUTwlZZ_lqmr8Epcqt1ZSPUszqWhW4/edit?usp=sharing"

julia> DataDeps.fetch_http(sheet_handler(url; format=:csv, sheet_gid=1251741166), ".")
┌ Info: Downloading
│   source = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13-LtgMi8evaxGxUTwlZZ_lqmr8Epcqt1ZSPUszqWhW4/export?format=csv&gid=1251741166"
│   dest = "./export?format=csv&gid=1251741166"
│   progress = NaN
│   time_taken = "0.0 s"
│   time_remaining = "NaN s"
│   average_speed = "∞ B/s"
│   downloaded = "404 bytes"
│   remaining = "∞ B"
└   total = "∞ B"
┌ Info: Downloading
│   source = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13-LtgMi8evaxGxUTwlZZ_lqmr8Epcqt1ZSPUszqWhW4/export?format=csv&gid=1251741166"
│   dest = "./download-test-julia-Sheet3.csv"
│   progress = NaN
│   time_taken = "0.0 s"
│   time_remaining = "NaN s"
│   average_speed = "7.324 KiB/s"
│   downloaded = "15 bytes"
│   remaining = "∞ B"
└   total = "∞ B"
"./download-test-julia-Sheet3.csv"

shell> cat download-test-julia-Sheet3.csv
Data on Sheet 3
```

## Download as a format that has all the sheets

If you use the `sheet_handler` call and pass in a format that supports multiple sheets, then you can just parse and manipulate the output locally.  Such as with `xlsx`.  I haven't tried it just now, but the call would be something like:

```
DataDeps.fetch_http(sheet_handler(url; format=:xlsx), ".")
```

Then find your favorite Julia Excel library and you are off to the races.